# How to include es13/es2022 features in current react - typescript project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

We know that ES 2022 Features are finally out. I am trying to use latest features in my current React - Typescript Project.

One feature that I am currently trying is .at() Method:

```js
const fruitsArray = ['banana', 'apple', 'orange', 'kiwi'];
console.log(fruitsArray.at(-1))
```

But I am getting TypeError: arr.at is not a function

In tsconfig,json, I changed "module": "esnext" to "module": "es2022". But still it didn't help.

Can someone help me on this please?

Comment: _"are finally out"_ - this entirely depends on where the code is being run. Just because ES2022 is final doesn't mean the browsers/engines have implemented them

Comment: `module` describes what types of modules are exported. The module format hasn't notably changed for a while (*maybe* top level await is bundled into that, I don't know) so what feature were you trying to enable?

Comment: "But still new features are not working." — Which features? [In what way](https://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/) don't they work?

Comment: update your node,js version to latest

Comment: @RezaMirzapour — Why does the version of Node.js matter? It's a React project. The target platform is almost certainly going to be browsers.

Comment: @evolutionxbox — ES2022 features have [pretty good support](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es2016plus/). I suspect multiple, compatible implementations is a prerequisite for them getting into the standard.

Comment: @Quentin Sorry for the missing pieces in my question. I have updated my question. I am trying to implement .at() function

Comment: Where are you getting the erorr? If it's a Typescript compiler error what version are you using?

Comment: @phuzi I am using latest typescript version 4.7.4. Also trying Top-level await feature. It is not working

Comment: Where are you seeing the error?

Comment: @phuzi I am seeing it in my browser(localhost:3000)

Comment: What browser are you using including version?

Comment: The Typescript/React details are misleading and the error you're seeing appears to not have anything to do with these.